# Ionic/Cordova plugins doesn't work iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode8

I'm developing a mobile app both for iOS and Android, I didn't have any issues on android.  But in iOS I encountered a problem when using plugins.  Plugins I used were `cordova-file-transfer` and social sharing by EddyVerbruggen.  Both plugins worked perfectly when I created my android app, but both got an issue when I did it in iOS.  Both plugin only works after I restart the app.  Why is that? I tried surrounding the code with `$ionicPlatform.ready` and `device.ready` but didn't help.  What am I missing?

Here's a sample sequence code:

```
$scope.myButton = function(){
    //I also tried surrounding this with 
    //document.addEventListener("deviceready", myfunction, false)

     $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
                //mycode here that uses the plugin ex. ($cordovaFileTransfer.download)
     });
}
```